# Azure inside out connection

Tags: azure, azure-functions, signalr, message-queue, azure-logic-apps

I am working on connecting my on premise app to Azure logic app. The problem here is that my network does not accept any inbound calls but is not limited in anyway to make outbound calls, so I have to open connection from inside out.

At the current state I have logic app, which at the end should make HTTP call to my on premise hosted web API, but this is a no-go solution for reasons mentioned above.

One of the ideas I had was to create Azure SignalR service, connect to it from within network and wait for the messages. For that to work I would also have to create proxy Azure Function to get request from Logic App and broadcast it to SignalR - i am not very skilled with Azure, but that does not look right to me.

Other idea was to use Azure message queue, but then I would have to run on schedule to read the messages, and one of the requirements is to have a real time connection.

Do you have any other ideas on what is the best way to create connection from .Net client to Azure?
Requirements are as follows:
Message has to originate from Logic Apps,
Connection has to be from inside firewall to outside,
Message has to be received in real time,
No new rules for firewall can be introduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A message queue seems like a good fit. When using a Azure Storage Queue you indeed need poll for new message. However, Azure Service Bus Queues push messages as stated by [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted#consider-using-service-bus-queues):

> As a solution architect/developer, you should consider using Service Bus queues when:
> [...]
> Your solution needs to receive messages without having to poll the queue. With Service Bus, you can achieve it by using a long-polling receive operation using the TCP-based protocols that Service Bus supports.

I've successfully used near realtime communication using Azure Service Bus Queues, so it is definitely possible.

Answer (score 0):

> Message has to originate from Logic Apps

***Yes, you can use Azure Service Bus Queues. Message can be originated from Logic Apps it can send a message to Service Bus Queue.***

[image]

[image]